# Ubuntu 18.04 custom Service start ( nginx ) on instance reboot/start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

OS :  Ubuntu 18.04

We have requirement, to **service nginx reload** after nginx service has started successfully on aws instance start / reboot.

I tried tinkering init.d/nginx but I don't see reload happened or not

```
    start)
            log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
            start_nginx
            case "$?" in
                    0|1) reload_nginx
                         log_end_msg $?
                         log_end_msg 0 ;;
                    2)   log_end_msg 1 ;;
            esac
            ;;
```

Am I doing in right way  are in there any better way to do it.

Comment: Huh? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is the temporary fix, till we find the exact cause for the another issue still we are facing. Here is my previous post

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1021036/wondering-how-nginx-reload-works-in-my-case. @Michael Hampton